# Why jquery ui draggable is slow in this example

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

In the jquery ui site, the draggable examples are fast. But with this markup, the plugin is terribly slow:

```
$("ul.projects").sortable({
    items: ".ui-state-default",
  containment:"parent",
  cursor:"move",
  cursorAt:{left: 90}
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/pietrofxq/pen/ejglm)

Comment: Seems to be related to your CSS3 effects. When removed the speed is normal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove all transitions for `ul.projects li`. It makes the animation slow.
Or turn off them for `.ui-sortable-helper`:

```
ul.projects li:not(.ui-sortable-helper) {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 6.5px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: Solves my problem. This is what I need :). Thank you very mych taggon.

Comment: You saved my life. :)